# how to use retryWhen() Rxandroid

Tags: java, android, recursion, rx-java2, rx-android

I call an expensive recursive function using RXJava. Most of the time it runs very quickly, however sometimes it will generate an take way too long

Is there a way I can use the `retryWhen()` after 5 seconds if the thread is still running?

```
 observable = getObservable(); ///Runs a recursive function
 mObserver = getSudokuPuzzleObserver();

 observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .retryWhen() // How to use retryWhen onNext() isn't called in 5 seconds
            .subscribe(mSudokuPuzzleObserver);
```

Comment: The `RetryWhen` operator responds to an `onError` notification from the source Observable and decide whether to resubscribe or not and regenerate new observable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it fits your solution but i thought of something like

```
    Observable observable = getObservable();
    observable.timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retry(e -> e instanceof TimeoutException)
            .subscribe(mSudokuPuzzleObserver);
```

`timeout` will throw exception if observable doesnt emit anything in 5 sec, and onError it will retry exact same observable if error was caused by timeout.